# How to keep track of selected object in Picker - SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

The following code effectively displays the dog's names and when selecting a dog, it outputs its color. What I would like to do is be able to track what object has been selected and be able to access all its attributes in the `onChange` method.

How can I access all attributes of the selected object inside the `onChange` method?

```
    class Dog:NSObject {
        var name = ""
        var color = ""
        var breed = ""
        
        init(name: String, color: String, breed: String) {
            self.name = name
            self.color = color
            self.breed = breed
        }
    }

    class DogService:ObservableObject{
        @Published var dogs:[Dog]
        
        init(){
            dogs = [Dog(name:"Pluto", color: "Brown", breed: "Golden Retriever"),
                    Dog(name: "Teddy", color: "White", breed: "Poodle"),
                    Dog(name: "Rocky", color: "Black", breed: "Labrador")]
        }
    }

    struct PickerTest: View {
        let dogService = DogService()
        @State private var selectedDog = ""
        
        var body: some View {
            Form {
                Picker("Dogs:", selection: $selectedDog) {
                    ForEach(dogService.dogs, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0.name).tag($0.color)
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: selectedDog) {dog in
                    print("Dog Color: \(dog)") // outputs, Brown, White or Black

                    // what I would like to do...  
                    // print("Dog Breed: \(dog.breed)") // should output, Golden Retriever, Poodle or Labrador
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should use a `struct` for your model -- not a `class`. SwiftUI isn't built for comparing reference types like this. Also, you should be using `@StateObject var` instead of `let` before `dogService = DogService()`

Comment: Instead of using the color as the tag use Dog and change the selected variable to a Dog type

Comment: @jnpdx - I have `@StateObject` in my production app, I just missed it in my code example, either way, it doesn't really matter for what I'm trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: @loremipsum - I changed `selectedDog` to `selectedDog:Dog?` and tag to `.tag($0)` and I get no errors but now the picker is not selectable, it just shows the first dog name, no matter what your selection is. Thanks.

Comment: Do `.tag($0 as Optional<Dog>)` or `.tag($0 as Dog?)`  types are very important

Comment: It actually *will* matter here, because you've used a reference type `Dog` so the object equality demands that it is the *same object*. By recreating the service every time, all of the models will be recreated as well and the identities will not be the same. Agree with @loremipsum's advice, as long as you switch to `struct`.

Comment: @loremipsum - Changing tag to `.tag($0 as Dog?)` did the trick. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `String` you can use `Dog`

```
struct PickerTest: View {
    let dogService = DogService()
    @State private var selectedDog: Dog? = nil //Types must match
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker("Dogs:", selection: $selectedDog) {
                ForEach(dogService.dogs, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0.name).tag($0 as Dog?) //Types must match
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedDog) {dog in
                print("Dog Color: \(dog)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also something to consider, in order for SwiftUI to know when variables have changed for an object a `class` has to be an `ObservableObject` with appropriate `@Published` variables or a `struct`. Your `class Dog:NSObject`, should be changed according to your requirements.

Comment: Can you please clarify something for me, are you saying that the `Dog` model class must conform to `ObservableObject` even though it doesn't really expose any `@Published` properties? `DogService ` is my observable object. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @fs_tigre if you will want the `body` to reload when you change variables it should be a `struct` or an `ObservableObject`

Comment: In my case 'Dog' will only be used within services/viewModels. But thank you for the advice.